# ControllerFactory for ApiController in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 project with MVC controllers already present, however I'd like to use the class `ApiController` for some new functionalities.

The existing controller factory returns an `IController` object which `ApiController` doesn't inherit from. What would be the best way to make another controller factory for `ApiController` derived controllers, and make both factories co-exist?

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory((IControllerFactory)new BuilderControllers.BuilderControllerFactory());

public class BuilderControllerFactory :IControllerFactory
{
    public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        string controllerType = string.Format("BuilderControllers.{0}Controller", controllerName);
        IController controller = null;
        try
        {
            controller = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(controllerType)) as IController;
        }
        catch (System.Exception x)
        {
            //-- handle any failed requests --
        }
        return controller;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also have MVC 4 solution, but I added ApiController directly in the solution and it works without a custom controller factory.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about different type of controllers here, one comes from IController and other is IHttpController. keep your existing factory for MVC controllers and also add

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),new MyControllerActivator());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector),new MyControllerSelector());

public class MyControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class MyControllerSelector : IHttpControllerSelector
{
    public HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return new HttpControllerDescriptor() {ControllerName="SomeController",ControllerType=typeof(MyApiController),Configuration=GlobalConfiguration.Configuration};
    }

    public IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> GetControllerMapping()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

you will have to play around with this idea to get what you want.
this should take care of your problem. But i still dont understand why you would be doing that as this will cause problems with dependency injection. i will take that you have your reasons.

Comment: Tbh I'm quite new to asp.net mvc I'm starting to explore ApiController because they seem to adjust better to Backbone.js. I'm getting a compilation error on your code 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: what exact version of mvc package are you using. and what is version of web api are you using. are you using nuget packages or GAC references ?

Comment: mvc: 4.0.01 api: 2.0.0.0 I'm using GAC references

Comment: I dont have that setup. cant seem to find mvc 4 in my GAC. i would need to install and stuff. do you think you can afford to remove GAC references for those things and use nuget instead. i.e. upgrade ?

Comment: The code is already posted on the question, what else do you need?